# Maven: execute cli command based on profile (if else)

Tags: maven, build

I tried to read and understand the profiles page of maven but I can't figure out how I can use profiles in an if-else-context to fit my needs.

The pom.xml in the project I'm working one has the following code already given:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
...
```

I'd like to implement something like (pseudo code)

```
if (profile(debug)){
    <arguments>run build-debug</arguments>
} else {
    <arguments>run build</arguments>
}
```

How can I do this with maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll have to declare 2 profiles. let's say "debug" and "prod". You'll have to write the whole plugin declaration in each profile with the corresponding parameters.

Something like:

```
<profiles> 
   <profile>
     <id>prod</id>
     <activation>
         <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
     </activation>
         <build>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                ...
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
   </profile>
   <profile>
     <id>debug</id>
         <build>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                ...
                <arguments>run build-debug</arguments>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

Notice that the `prod` profile will be active if no explicit profile is set. To run the debug profile just run:

```
mvn package -P debug
```

You can't achieve it with if-else because that's not the way that build profiles are built.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to understand maven configuration a little bit better.